# Change slash to dot in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, datetime

I am wondering how it is possible to change mm/yyyy to mm.yyyy in biblatex.
Are these used correctly?

```
alldates=terse
labeldate=year
```

if I say labeldate = year, wouldn't that usually lead to omitting the month? Or did I get that wrong. Is terse the right option if I want a date like mm.yyyy?
(I have been checking the documentation but not really sure about the / . replacement!
Sorry!

[image: Example]
MWE:

```
 \documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,online]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{Chafe.1974,
author = {Chafe, Wallace L.}, 
 title = {An Approach to Verbalization and Translation by Machine. Final Report}, 
 month = {10},
 year = {1974}, 
 institution = {{California University, Berkely}}, 
 address = {New York} 
 }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\parencite{Chafe.1974} 
\clearpage
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Marijn unfortunately the date dd.mm.yyyy looks correct, but mm.yyyy doesn't for me :/

Comment: For that case you need to change `/` into `.` in the fourth line from the bottom in `\mkbibdateshort`, i.e. it should be `\iffieldundef{#3}{.}{\adddot\thinspace}`.

Comment: Or `\adddot` instead of `.` if you want to use Biblatex conventions of course.

Comment: Thank you! @Marijn - do you know why it looks fine for dd.mm.yyyy without amendments though?

Comment: You already use german/ngerman as language for Biblatex, this has the dot notation predefined for full dates - I didn't notice this when I suggested the duplicate. For the month/year version however the German settings define a slash by default, which you can change by modifying a different part of `\mkbibdateshort`.

Comment: Do we need to reopen this because the proposed duplicate does not answer the question? Or did you manage to find a solution via the proposed duplicate so that a separate answer is not required?

Comment: @moewe the proposed duplicate provides 99% of the answer and my first comment above is the final 1%, so I guess it can stay closed. But I'm also fine with reopening and converting my comments into an answer, if the OP prefers that.

Comment: @moewe I was able to solve the issue thanks to marijn :) thank you!